'set' vs 'variable' in Tcl
afaik, there are two ways two create and assign a namespaced variable in Tcl:
namespace eval ::myspace:: {
  variable foo 1
}
set ::myspace::bar 2

afaict, the two are equivalent:
info vars ::myspace::*
# ::myspace::foo ::myspace::bar

I have wondered for a while, whether they are really equivalent (and which one is the preferred form).

I'm pretty sure this has been asked and answered before

@Filburt that's not a very helpful or welcoming response. I have to confess that I don't find the distinction clear either. Tcl's documentation leaves something to be desired here. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable can give us the definitive answer.

@Filburt it probably has been asked and answered before. However, I did do my background research before I asked (obviously consulting the Tcl-docs; and doing a websearch with pretty much the search terms you were using), and was not able to identify such a duplicate question (not to speak of an answer to the question) - as you are certainly aware, otherwise you hopefully would have just voted to close this issue, pointing out the duplicate.

I see that @Filburt and a few others have closed this question. I don't think this is reasonable or welcoming, and voted to reopen.

@Filburt If a question has been asked before, you should vote to close as a duplicate, not vote to close as opinion-based: asking if two syntax forms are equivalent in effect/behaviour, or if they may have (subtle?) differences is not asking for opinions.

The set command is a basic operation. If you give it two arguments, it resolves the variable with the name typically preferring a local variable over anything else) and writes the value to the variable, returning the contents of the variable. (Usuallly the same thing as the value you wrote.) With one argument it reads the variable instead.
The variable command ensures that that name will resolve to the variable with that name in the current namespace; in a context with local variables (inside a procedure or method) it makes a link from the local variable with that name to the resolved namespace variable. And can write a simple variable too, if you supply a value. It can process multiple variables... but I don't use that much. It has an empty result.
If you use a fully-qualified variable name with set, you can write any namespace variable directly. It's just a different way of looking up the underlying reality; variables are not their names, after all, a name is just a way to find a variable.
The linking mechanism is also used by global, upvar and namespace upvar. It is very fast (after formation), typically involving a single extra deference in the bytecode engine.

so for my specific example, when initializing named variables in a namespace, when I do not care about return values, the two are indeed equivalent(?). which one would be considered better style?

Better style? Depends on what you think of it as. I'd probably use variable in that case; I'm happy with nesting things. But using the fully qualified form is definitely not wrong at all; I use that for the env and tcl_platform globals, for example.
